# Finding the highest scoring word in a string, based on value of letter?

Tags: php

Given a string of words, I need to find the highest scoring word. Each letter of a word scores points according to its position in the alphabet: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc. I need to return the highest scoring word as a string.

So in the string `'man i need a taxi up to ubud'` the correct return string would be taxi since it has high value letters like t and x.

My confusion lies in how to assign each letter in each word a value. I understand to explode the input string and then foreach over that to explode the words but how to increment the value based on the order in the alphabet? I'm very confused.

```
function high($x) {
    $alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
                "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", 
                "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
    $nA = array_flip($alphabet);

    $words = explode(" ", $x);
    foreach($words as $w) {
      explode("", $w);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why not split up your algorihtm? One part is "split up by word", another one "generate score per word". So, what have you tried to make it work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: My problem is in connecting the two. This is supposed to be within one function, I can't think of how to connect the splitting and generating the score.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need one function? Make it two, to seperate the concerns. If you like you can merge that later, but seperating it during development might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't actually care about the score, more the word with the highest characters, you can use `ord()` to work out the ascii value.  This has the alphabet in ascending order and so gives a higher value - but it's still based on position.

This splits the words, then for each word adds the ascii value and keeps a track of the highest...

```
function high($x) {
    // Split sentence into words (lower cased)
    $words = explode(" ", strtolower($x));
    $max = 0;
    $maxWord = '';
    foreach($words as $w) {
        // Keep track of 'value' of word
        $value = 0;
        // For each letter of the word ($i)...
        for ( $i = 0, $len = strlen($w); $i < $len; $i++ )  {
            // $w[$i]  is the letter we are dealing with (treat a string as an array)
            // Take the ascii value of this character and adjust it by 'a'
            $value += (ord($w[$i]) -ord('a'));
        }
        // Check if the new highest value
        if ( $value > $max )    {
            $max = $value;
            $maxWord = $w;
        }
    }
    return $maxWord;
}
```

Comment: Quite clever using the `ord()` function, didn't think of that.

Comment: Very nice solution but it seems not to work? **"Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected: 'volcano'
Actual  : 'climbing'"** Maybe that's a bug? I'm pretty sure **volcano** is higher in value.

Comment: **"'what time are we climbing up the volcano**"

Comment: I've updated the loop and changed it to `(ord($w[$i]) -ord('a'));`.

Comment: Can you try explaining this more? I feel so stupid for now getting it right away :(

Comment: You should be aware of hos this approach treats special characters and differentiates between uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Can you explain `-ord('a')`?

Comment: That is just adjusting the value to be 0-25 (rather than just the ascii value).

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each word, as you said - and for each word, determine its score. Then you need to save down the score of that word, and the word itself, or the position of that word. If the next score you calculate has a greater score than the one you have saved, overwrite - otherwise, carry on to the next iteration. Finally, return the value.

Use `strtolower()` to ensure that the words are lowercase, otherwise a string like `A man with a XRAY` would not find `XRAY` as the highest scoring word.

```php
function high($input) {
    // Initialize: Convert the string to lowercase, and generate an array of the alphabet
    $input = strtolower($input);
    $alphabet = range('a', 'z');
    $values = array_flip($alphabet);

    // Split the words into an array, and declare initial scores
    $words = explode(" ", $input);
    $highestScore = null;
    $highestIndex = null;
    
    // Iterate over each word
    foreach($words as $k=>$w) {
        // Calculate the score of the current word
        // The score is the position of the flipped alphabet array, or 0 if its not in the lsit
        $score = array_sum(array_map(function($v) use ($values) {
            return $values[$v] ?? 0;
        }, str_split($w)));

        // If the current score is higher than the previous highest, overwrite it
        if ($highestScore < $score) {
            $highestScore = $score;
            $highestIndex = $k;
        }
    }

    // Return the word at the index where the score was the highest
    // If there were no scores (if $input is empty), return a default message
    return $words[$highestIndex] ?? 'N/A - No words found';
}
```

The `array_map()` function will return an array of all the individual values of that word (each letter), so we use `array_sum()` to get the full sum of the array.

Since we use `return $values[$v] ?? 0;` and only create values from `a-z`, any other characters will have a score of 0. As the string is transformed to lowercase, this means that it will treat `a` and `A` with the same score of 1. Special characters like `!?#` and so on would get a score of 0.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/4ESFG